# Google Calendar API - Request URL 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, events, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get events from my calendar by using the Google API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="googleCalendar.js"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="calendarContainer">
            <div>
                <button type="button" id="authorize-button"><?= _("Google Calendar Events"); ?></button>
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <h2><?= _("Events"); ?></h2><br>
                <ul id="events"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

googleCalendar.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clientId = '{my_client_id}';
    var apiKey = '{my_api_key}';
    var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

    $("#authorize-button").click(function(){
        handleClientLoad();
    });

    function handleClientLoad()
    {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
        checkAuth();
    }

    function checkAuth()
    {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true},
        handleAuthResult);
    }

    function handleAuthResult(authResult)
    {
        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        if (authResult) {
            //authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            makeApiCall();
        } else {
            authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
            authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        }
    }

    function handleAuthClick(event)
    {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
            {client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false},
            handleAuthResult
        );
        return false;
    }

    function makeApiCall()
    {
        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
            var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                'calendarId': 'primary'
            });

            request.execute(function(resp) {
                console.log(resp);
                for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                   li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.items[i].summary));
                document.getElementById('events').appendChild(li);
                }
            });
        });
    }

});
```

When I click the button in order to get my events I get nothing. Then I inspect my page and I get this:

> Request URL: 
>   https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key={my_api_key}
>
> Status Code: 404 Not found

Pasting that URL in my browser I get this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "notFound",
                "message": "Not Found"
            }
        ],
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    }
}
```

Why do I get a 404 not found and I don't get the list of events from my calendar?

Comment: Might be because it's using `content.googleapis.com` instead of `www.googleapis.com`. Not really sure though.

Comment: I was thinking the same but I do not know how my variable scopes (var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar') becomes content.googleapis.com?

Comment: Are you actually using `googleapis.com/auth/calendar` as the scope or are you using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`?

Comment: As you see in my code I am using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

Comment: Just checking because your comment doesn't include the `htttps://www.` which is documented as part of the scope.